# How do I know what characters I need to escape in regular expressions?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I try to get rows from an XML file with [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep), but I'm not so good with regular expressions yet and I don't know which characters I need to escape in order to get this regular expression string to work:

```
grep -o -P '<row value="[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\/:=_]*" count="[0-9]*">[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\/:=_]*</row>'
```

I tried escaping every character, but that didn't work. What is the solution?

Comment: what is the text you are trying to match?

Comment: Here's a great resource to try the regex online: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/
And here's a page with a lot of information regarding regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: This is an example: <row value="t/test:Tester" count="5">Test Tester</row>

Comment: If one is not so good in something, it is always a good idea to read the fine manual.

Comment: @ingo, i wouldn't have minded if you had posted one

Comment: @Chris What should your output look like? May be you just need `cut` or `awk` instead of `grep` and a complex `regex`

Comment: Missing space in content part, try this `'<row value="[\w./:=-]*" count="[0-9]*">[ \w./:=-]*</row>'`. But because your missing a space tells you that this regex might be inadequate to parse xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You regex does not allow spaces in the text. The text you are trying to match has `Test Tester` which won't match your pattern `[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\/:=_ ]*`. You need to add a space to it.

Try this:

```
grep -o -P '<row value="[a-zA-Z0-9\-./:=_]*" count="[0-9]*">[a-zA-Z0-9\-./:=_ ]*</row>'
```

Comment: Actually you don't need to escape the dot when it's inside a character class. The following characters needs to be escaped `^-]\ ` inside a character class. The dash does not need to be escaped if it's the first or last character though

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're not a daily regex user so I would suggest you use a tool like [txt2re](http://txt2re.com/) to help you build this.